# I have a problem with a math quiz in python

Tags: python

I am very new at python and i just wanted to make a pprogramm with a question how much is 23*10? and if the user answers 230 it will print true but if not it would print false and i dont know how to ... this is my first attempt

```
Question = input("How much is 23 * 10? ") if Question == "230":print("True")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. In particular, your title should concisely summarize your question. Your current question doesn't give us any useful information.

Comment: Spend some more time with [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: [`if`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) is explained very early in the tutorial.

Comment: Look at @celius-stingher [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59652021/2544873). It should solve your problem. Then mark it as solved.
You can keep your one liner, even if it is worse, but separe statements  with `;` like that: `Question = input("How much is 23 * 10? "); if Question == "230": print("True")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty much what you made, lacking indentation and the `else`. Also, I'm adding `int()` before `input()` because otherwise, the value provided will be considered as a string instead of a number. It doesn't make much difference if you are then comparing it with a string `"230"` but I just thought I'll change it a bit to show you another perspective.

```
question = int(input("How much is 23 * 10? "))

if question == 230:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

As I explained before, if you do not wish to use `int` then you must compare the value to a string:

```
question = input("How much is 23 * 10? ")
if question == "230":
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```